# How to disable the calendar alarm for another device?

Tags: iphone, ios

I have an iPhone with iOS 6 which has an Apple ID bound and from this iPhone I usually set alarms for the calendar.

My brother has another iPhone with iOS 6 too, and we are sharing the same Apple ID. The problem is that he gets notified for my alarms. How do I disable calendar alarms just for his iPhone and keep getting notified on mine?

Comment: Why are you sharing an Apple ID when they are free?

Comment: You're right, but my brother either wasn't able to create one or was too lazy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way would be to disable Reminders on your brother's phone completely. Unlike iMessage, Reminders can't be set per device, but is bound to the Apple ID.

We may see Apple bring the functionality to Reminders in the future.